# Error al cargar archivo en formulario html

Tags: python, django, django-models

Estoy creando una aplicación usando django donde se deben cargar archivos y estos serán guardados en la carpeta de un proyecto.

El problema reside en que cuando lleno el formulario desde el *admin* de django me permite guardar el archivo sin problemas, pero cuando lo hago desde la vista de formulario html no me carga el archivo.

**model.py**:

```
def content_file_name(instance, filename):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = '%s %s %s.%s' % (instance.tipoSoporte, instance.codigoSoporte, instance.cargado, ext) 
    return '/'.join([str(instance.idProyecto), str("Legales"), filename])
class SoporteLegal(models.Model):
    idProyecto = models.ForeignKey(Proyecto, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    soporte = (
        ('01 Contrato','Contrato'),
        ('06 Otros avales', 'Otros avales'),
        )
    tipoSoporte = models.CharField('Tipo de soporte', max_length=50, choices=soporte, blank=False)
    codigoSoporte = models.CharField('Número de soporte', max_length=30, blank=True)
    cargado = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    archivoSoporte = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name, validators=[validarExtensionValidaLegales], blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.idProyecto) + " - " + str(self.tipoSoporte) + " - " + str(self.codigoSoporte)
```

**views.py**:

```
def ResgistrarSoporteLegale(request):
    titulo = "Registro Soportes legales"

    form = RegistroSoporteLegal(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        print(instance)
        form.save()

    context = {
        "titulo": titulo,
        "form": form,
        }
    return render(request, "proyecto/registrosoportelegal.html", context)
```

**forms.py**:

```
class RegistroSoporteLegal(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SoporteLegal
        fields ='__all__'
```

En el **html**:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form method='POST' action="">{% csrf_token %}

            {{ form.as_p }}

    <input type="submit" value='Registrar'>
    </form>
</div>
```

Como he dicho, todo funciona bien pero al momento de intentar registrar el soporte desde el formulario html en el campo del `FileField` que se subirá aparece la alerta de que "este campo es obligatorio" y no guarda el formulario.

Les pido el favor de ayudarme y estoy atento a ustedes.

Comment: Solucionado: era necesario agregar en el html <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="">

Comment: Hola, crea la respuesta a tu solución y acéptala cuando puedas. De esa forma la pregunta no queda abierta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado: era necesario agregar en el html `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="">`